# Does the "Urgent wish for children" card in Caverna allow construction of all types of dwellings?

Tags: caverna

The B side of the "Wish for children" card titled "Urgent wish for children" requires you to build a "Dwelling" prior to family growth. Dwelling is written with a capital D on the card. Does that mean that you are required to build the regular dwelling priced at 4 wood, 3 stone that gives you 3 goal points or are you allowed to build any of the different types of dwellings?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the capital D in "Dwelling" has any significance.  In the rule book *Dwelling* is always capitalized.  I would think that you could build any of the Dwellings.  If you couldn't, I think there would be a specific explanation in the rule book.

> There are 6 different types of Dwellings.  Every Dwelling provides room for one or two dwarfs. (P. 15)

Comment: If Dwelling is always spelled with a capital D in the rules we can't possibly differentiate the dwelling priced at 4 wood, 3 stone that gives you 3 goal points and the general class of Dwellings though.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this under the description of the Couple Dwelling that definitively answers this question in the positive

"The Couple dwelling provides room for 2 Dwarfs. You can get these Dwarfs one at a time with a Family growth action. (Even if you build this Furnishing tile on the “Urgent wish for children” Action space, you may only grow your family once with that action.)"

So yes we can assume 'Dwellings' to mean all types. Interestingly i also just learned that you can only use the 'dwelling for 2 wood and 2 stone' quest once.

Comment: where do you get that you can only do the dwelling quest one?? I don't see that... :(